# Show if I have visited a website before

Tags: firefox-extensions, tracking

Looking for an app or extension that would tell me if I have visited a website before. I am not looking for a historical website tracker in a searchable form like you would use to track where your kids have been. I want some type of indicator that displays if I have visited a particular site before in the past. I do a lot of research and post on a lot of forms. If I arrive at a site, I would like an instant way to be notified that I have already been here so that I can look somewhere else.

I had a custom FireFox extension written for me a few years ago. It will not work with newer versions of FireFox. I would much rather find an alternative.

Comment: Google chrome do that for you in 'History' ...

Comment: +1...Would be nice thing to have for people who scour web....chrome does it partially...only for TLD...it does check specific page..

Comment: Agreed.  Just an icon that lights up if the page you're on was in your history previous to this visit.  Very handy.

Comment: I'll also recommend the X-Marks add-on.  Aside from syncing bookmarks across every major browser (also handy), it has a 5-star rating feature (which also syncs).  I originally thought it was useless, but it's actually a great way to see if a glance if you've already reviewed a page and found it worthwhile (or useless).

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but when you right click in a page in firefox and click on page info choose the security tab and look there for Have I visited this website prior to today?

And finding an extension might be hard [i'm not ff expert] speically with their current development cycle and how much fast it is.